# C# WSDL API how to access an array?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wsdl

```
var results = client.CancelRx(new ServiceReference2.CancelRxRequest()
{
    PracticeLocation = new ServiceReference2.PracticeLocationType()
    {
        Identification = new ServiceReference2.FacilityID()
        {
            ID = "101",
            MedicareNumber = "101",
            Ogrn = "101"
        },
        BusinessName = "Name №1",
    }
}
```

How to access methods is clear, according to this principle, but how to access an array, I don't know, can anyone help?

`public partial class DrugCoded : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

```
    private object[] itemsField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("CompositeProductCode", typeof(DrugProductCodeWithDoseText), Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("IndividualManufactured", typeof(BooleanCode), Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ProductClarifyingFreeText", typeof(string), Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ProductCode", typeof(DrugProductCodeWithText), Order=0)]
    public object[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }`
```

How to contact "ProductCode"

Comment: Define "access an array". You access arrays like any other member, and array index syntax is `foo[index]`.

Comment: What specific array do you want to access, and what trouble are you having when you try? It's unclear what the real issue is. As CodeCaster says, using arrays is standard throughout C#. Just because this code was generated from a WSDL doesn't change that fact. So if you have a particular problem, please explain it in detail and give an example.

Comment: Made changes to the question

Comment: I have the same issue, have you found a solution?

Question is: How to add such a "item" to the Items object array?  { new Item("CompositeProductCode", new DrugProductCodeWithDoseText()  }) or similar